# Overlay image on an other

Tags: lightning, css, images

Is it possible to overlay image on an other ?
I want to do that to display notification on a Logo.
I have one regular Logo and an other with red dot.

With this code it is working but sometimes it takes little time to pass from the dotted to the regular Logo :

```
    <lightning:layout  class="slds-border_bottom " >
        <lightning:layoutItem size="6"> </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="6" >
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.notif}">
            <img src="{!$Resource.Logo2Dot}" Style="height: 35px; "  class="slds-float_right"/>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <img src="{!$Resource.Logo2}" Style="height: 35px; "  class="slds-float_right"/>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
```

I am wondering if it is possible to overlay the 2 logo and display the dotted logo on the top only if needed. if it is possible I will not have any time between displaying of the 2 logo.

```
    <lightning:layout  class="slds-border_bottom " >
        <lightning:layoutItem size="6"> </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="6" >
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.notif}">
                <img src="{!$Resource.XfindLogo2Dot}" Style="height: 35px; "  class="slds-float_right overlay"/>
            </aura:if>
            <img src="{!$Resource.XfindLogo2}" Style="height: 35px; "  class="slds-float_right"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do this, you just need to do some CSS positioning:

```
<div class="container">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.notif}">
            <img src="{!$Resource.XfindLogo2Dot}" />
        </aura:if>
        <img src="{!$Resource.XfindLogo2}" />
</div>
```

Then, in your CSS:

```
.THIS div.container {
  position: relative;
}
.THIS div.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 35px;
}
.THIS div.container img.overlay {
  z-index: 1;
}
```